# Passing Acumatica DAC as parameter

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a snippet of code that is repeated over and over again to retrieve DAC field DisplayName attribute from each of the DAC fields in a given DAC.  I would like to refactor this code into a function and simply pass the necessities as arguments.  I cannot find a graceful way to handle the DAC field.  Can someone please assist?

I have the following code written that is used multiple times for each DAC field:

```
string displayName = string.Empty();

foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attribute in ext.DefAddress.Cache.GetAttributes<Address.countryID>(newaddr))
                {
                    if (attribute is PXUIFieldAttribute)
                    {
                        PXUIFieldAttribute attrib = attribute as PXUIFieldAttribute;
                        displayName = attrib.DisplayName;
                    }
                }
```

I would like to refactor this code into a function like this:

```
string displayName = GetDisplayName(***Address.addressLine1***, ext.DefAddress.Cache, newaddr);
```

Where Address.addressLine1 is the DAC field, ext.DefAddress.Cache is PXCache and newaddr is Address DAC.

I envision something like this (which does not work

```
protected string GetDisplayName(***Type field***, PXCache cache, Address DAC)
        {
            foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attribute in cache.GetAttributes<***field***>(DAC))
            {
                if (attribute is PXUIFieldAttribute)
                {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute attrib = attribute as PXUIFieldAttribute;
                    displayName = attrib.DisplayName;
                }
            }
        }
```

No matter how hard I try, I cannot figure out how to pass the field as an argument to the function.  Any assistance would be much appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need a generic function to do this:

```
        protected string GetDisplayName<T>(PXCache cache, Address DAC) where T : IBqlField
        {
            var displayName = "";
            foreach (var attribute in cache.GetAttributes<T>(DAC))
            {
                if (attribute is PXUIFieldAttribute attrib)
                {
                   displayName = attrib.DisplayName;
                }
            }

            return displayName;
        }
```

Usage:

```
var displayName = GetDisplayName<Address.addressLine1>(ext.DefAddress.Cache, newaddres);
```